# Wildfly: ExceptionMapper not triggered with RestEasy JSR-303 Bean Validation

Tags: json, wildfly, resteasy, bean-validation, wildfly-8

I'm using Bean Validation with RestEasy in Wildfly 8.2.0.Final:

```
@Path("/user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserEndpoint
{
    //more code

    @GET
    @Path("/encrypt/{email}")
    public Response fetchEncryptedId(@PathParam("email") @NotNull String email)
    {
        String encryptedUserId = userService.getEncryptedUserId(email);

        return Response.ok().entity(new UserBo(encryptedUserId)).build();
    }
}
```

This basically works. Now I'd like to get the response as JSON object but I can't get it working. All my "application" exceptions are handled by my Exception Mapper, this works:

```
@Provider
public class DefaultExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>
{
    private static final String MEDIA_TYPE = "application/json";

    private LoggingService loggingService;

    @EJB
    public void setLoggingService(LoggingService loggingService)
    {
        this.loggingService = loggingService;
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception)
    {
        ResponseObject responseObject = new ResponseObject();
        responseObject.registerExceptionMessage(exception.getMessage());

        if (exception instanceof ForbiddenException)
        {
            loggingService.log(LogLevel.ERROR, ((ForbiddenException)exception).getUserId(), ExceptionToStringMapper.map(exception));
            return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).type(MEDIA_TYPE).entity(responseObject).build();
        }

        //more handling

        loggingService.log(LogLevel.ERROR, "", ExceptionToStringMapper.map(exception));
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).type(MEDIA_TYPE).entity(responseObject).build();
    }
}
```

But bean validation somehow bypasses it. Then I thought about using **Throwable** instead of Exception but it didn't help either. I guess the ExceptionMapper is not triggered because there is some life cycle problem with JAX-RS and JSR303. But how can I syncronize them to handle bean validation exceptions?
Additional information: The exception passes the `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter` so I could write some workaround by implementing the filter method in a subclass, but this is not clean solution. The target is to handle the exceptions in the Exception mapper.

Comment: I think the exception mapper is the way to go. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516516/how-to-catch-resteasy-bean-validation-errors. Not sure why this does not work in this case. Have you tried registering a dedicated mapper as suggested by the other post?

Comment: @Hardy Me neither, that's why I ask. The mapper from the post is the same as mine, whereby mine is even more tolerant since I basically catch any exception not just ConstraintViolationException.
(I'm in with the debugger but it's just not invoked)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not always the case that your `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` will catch all exception under the `Exception` hierarchy. If there is another more specific mapper, say one for `RuntimeException`, *that* mapper will be used for all exception of `RuntimeException` and its subtypes.

That being said (assuming you're using `resteasy-validation-provider-11`), there is already a [`ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/providers/resteasy-validator-provider-11/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/api/validation/ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper.java) that handles `ValidationException`.

```
@Provider
public class ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper 
        implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException>
```

This mapper is automatically registered. It returns results in the form of a [`ViolationReport`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/providers/resteasy-validator-provider-11/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/api/validation/ViolationReport.java). The client needs to set the `Accept` header to `application/json` in order to see a response similar to

```
{
  "exception":null,
  "fieldViolations":[],
  "propertyViolations":[],
  "classViolations":[],
  "parameterViolations":[
    {
      "constraintType":"PARAMETER",
      "path":"get.arg0",
      "message":"size must be between 2 and 2147483647",
      "value":"1"}
  ],
  "returnValueViolations":[]
}
```

You can see more at [Violation reporting](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.11.Final/userguide/html/Validation.html#d4e2470).

If you want to completely override this behavior, you can create a more specific mapper for [`ResteasyViolationException`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/providers/resteasy-validator-provider-11/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/api/validation/ResteasyViolationException.java), which is the exception thrown by the RESTeasy validator

```
@Provider
public class MyValidationMapper
        implements ExceptionMapper<ResteasyViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ResteasyViolationException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, both solutions work. I will accept it when I can award the bounty.