# Customizing JAX-RS response when a ConstraintViolationException is thrown by Bean Validation

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, bean-validation

Bean Validation is a good option to validate objects, but how to customize the response of a REST API (using RESTeasy) when a `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown?

For example:

```java
@POST
@Path("company")
@Consumes("application/json")
public void saveCompany(@Valid Company company) {
    ...
}
```

A request with invalid data will return a HTTP `400` status code with the following body:

```
[PARAMETER]
[saveCompany.arg0.name]
[{company.name.size}]
[a]
```

It's nice but not enough, I would like to normalize these kind of errors in a JSON document.

How can I customize this behavior?

Comment: Seems like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516516/how-to-catch-resteasy-bean-validation-errors

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With JAX-RS can define an [`ExceptionMapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) to handle [`ConstraintViolationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html)s.

From the [`ConstraintViolationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html), you can get a set of [`ConstraintViolation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html), that exposes the constraint violation context, then map the details you need to an abitrary class and return in the response:

```java
@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper 
       implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {

        List<ValidationError> errors = exception.getConstraintViolations().stream()
                .map(this::toValidationError)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(errors)
                       .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

    private ValidationError toValidationError(ConstraintViolation constraintViolation) {
        ValidationError error = new ValidationError();
        error.setPath(constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString());
        error.setMessage(constraintViolation.getMessage());
        return error;
    }
}
```

```java
public class ValidationError {

    private String path;
    private String message;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

---

If you use Jackson for JSON parsing, you may want to have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44281799/1426227), showing how to get the value of the actual JSON property.

Comment: Thanks, but the provider seem to be ignored ! (resteasy 3.0.19.Final, wildfly 10.1.0.final), any tips ?

Comment: @Francois What is you application like? Do you have a `web.xml`? Do you extend `Application`? More details are welcome to help you.

Comment: yes i have a web.xml but it s empty, and i have a classic rest api app @ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(CustomerService.class));
    }
}

Comment: @Francois You are overriding the `getClasses()` method, hence the auto-scanning won't pick the provider automatically. Register also the provider: `return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(CustomerService.class, ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.class));`

Comment: My Mapper that implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> does not pick up the Exception and I get the same result as the OP. What am I missing ? (Resteasy, Wildfy11 RC)

Comment: great simple construction! Good job