# How to catch ConstraintViolationExceptions in a REST Method

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly, resteasy

Before marking this as a duplicate: **I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308101/customizing-jax-rs-response-when-a-constraintviolationexception-is-thrown-by-bea) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516516/how-to-catch-resteasy-bean-validation-errors) that an ExceptionMapper will solve my problem, but for some reason it does not catch the ConstraintViolationException.**

**Update**
The problem is solved: Using a separate, more specific ExceptionMapper works (one that implements ExceptionMapper< ConstraintViolationException >). **But I don't fully understand why a more general exception mapper** (one that implements ExceptionMapper< Exception >) **does NOT catch my ConstraintViolationException.**

---

**Original question:**

I am introducing **bean validation** to my REST Methods:

```
@PUT
public Response updateUser(@NotNull @Valid UserUpdateDTO userUpdateDTO) {
    return ResponseUtil.ok(userService.updateUser(userUpdateDTO));
}
```

When a validation fails, I get a 400 response:

```
[PARAMETER]
[updateUser.arg0.initials]
[Initials must be between 3 and 5]
[AD]
```

I would like to **catch the ConstraintViolationException before the response is sent** because I have my own ResponseFactory.

Here is my ExceptionMapper (that works with my other exceptions!)

```
@Provider
public class ApiExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception e) {

        Throwable cause = (e instanceof EJBException) && e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause() : e;

        if (cause instanceof BadRequestException) {
            logger.error("BadRequest", cause);
            return ResponseUtil.badRequest(cause.getMessage());
        } else if (cause instanceof ForbiddenException) {
            logger.error("Forbidden", cause);
            return ResponseUtil.forbidden(cause.getMessage());
        } else if (cause instanceof ServerException) {
            logger.error("ServerException", cause);
            return ResponseUtil.serverError(cause.getMessage());
        } else if (cause instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            return ResponseUtil.badRequest("Validation failed");
        }

        // Default
        logger.error("unexpected exception while processing request", cause);
        return ResponseUtil.serverError(cause);
    }
}
```

**The ExceptionMapper is not even called** when a validation problem occurs, and I get the default 400 error right away.

What am I doing wrong ? I suspect that it has something to do with the fact that the exception is not thrown within the method's body, but rather in its signature.

I am using Wildfly 11 RC and its default validation

Comment: Do you have the `@Provider` annotation on your ExceptionMapper?

Comment: I do. I'll update my post

Comment: While it would be ugly, perhaps you could do "manual" validation in the method to verify your hypothesis that the exception is thrown before JAX-RS really gets involved.  It makes sense but I'm not positive.

Comment: But the two other questions I quoted seem to have been resolved with a ExceptionMapper, but they call @valid in the signature as well.

Comment: @stdunbar a "manual validation" does not throw any exception, it just returns a Set of constraint violations. I could use this as a workaround, but using @ valid would be much more convenient...

Answer (score 2):

Given a Rest Service such as:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/people")
public class PersonService {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "people")
    private EntityManager em;

    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(@Valid Person person) throws DuplicateKeyException {
        em.persist(person);
        return Response.created(UriBuilder.fromResource(PersonService.class)
                .path(PersonService.class, "getPerson")
                .resolveTemplate("id", person.getId()).build())
                .build();
    }

}
```

then the following ExceptionMapper works just fine by itself:

```
@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException>{

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    private static class ConstraintViolationBean {
        private final String propertyName;
        private final String message;
        private final String invalidValue;

        private ConstraintViolationBean(ConstraintViolation constraintViolation) {
            final StringBuilder propertyPath = new StringBuilder();
            for (Path.Node node: constraintViolation.getPropertyPath()) {
                if (propertyPath.length() > 0) {
                    propertyPath.append('.');
                }
                propertyPath.append(node.getName());
            }
            this.propertyName = propertyPath.toString();
            this.message = constraintViolation.getMessage();
            this.invalidValue = constraintViolation.getInvalidValue().toString();
        }

        public String getPropertyName() {
            return propertyName;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public String getInvalidValue() {
            return invalidValue;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Constraint violation: {}", exception.getMessage());
        List<ConstraintViolationBean> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ConstraintViolation cv : exception.getConstraintViolations()) {
            messages.add(new ConstraintViolationBean(cv));
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity(messages)
                .build();
    }

}
```

This is real working (not production) code that I have been messing with for fun. There is also an ExceptionMapper for the `DuplicateKeyException`.

You can find the source on github at [jaxrs-people](https://github.com/sfcoy/jaxrs-people), which is essentially an experiment.

One thing I have noticed is that EJBExceptions seem to be unwrapped before the ExceptionMapper is selected and invoked.

### Update:

Now, if I add the following implementation of `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` to the deployment, then this one is invoked and the remaining exception mappers are ignored.

```
@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Therefore it seems that because your `ApiExceptionMapper` is actually catching everything and your other ExceptionMappers will be ignored.

It looks like you need to either implement a separate ExceptionMapper for each of `BadRequestException`, `ForbiddenException` and `ServerException`, or some common ancestor class that is not `Exception` or `RuntimeException`.

I think that separate implementations would be better because code without `if` statements is easier to unit test.

### What the Spec says:

§4.4 of "JAX-RS: Java™ API for RESTful Web Services (v2.0)" contains the statement:

> When choosing an exception mapping provider to map an exception, an implementation MUST use the provider whose generic type is the nearest superclass of the exception.

This behaviour corresponds with what we have experienced here.

Comment: My main problem is that the ExceptionMapper is not even invoked. How come yours is ?

Comment: Very interesting update. But I only have one ExceptionMapper - and even using the one from your GenericExceptionMapper example, it does not catch the ConstraintViolationException.

Comment: So I tried this: ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> and it caught my Exception. I still don't understand why Exception alone did not catch it, but your tips in your update solved my problem. Thanks, I can award the bounty in 4 hours

Comment: The other thing I was going to suggest was to ensure that you don't have any JAX-RS implementations polluting your deployment. That will certainly muddy the water for you.

Comment: You solved my problem, but I still don't understand why my only ExceptionMapper<Exception> does not catch the ConstraintViolationException, but a ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> does. According to the docs, isn't ExceptionMapper<Exception> the provider whose generic type is the nearest superclass of the exception ? (if it's the only one)